# Problems establishing a secure SSL/TLS channel after a certain number of successful runs with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, x509certificate

I use a C# HttpClient to access an REST-API-endpoint with a PKI certificate authentication/authorization.

The connection works for a certain number of queries without problems. According to the endpoint, there are some limits, which I list here for completeness:

- Number of requests for an already established TLS connection = 200
- Timeout how long to wait to be able to send another request over the same connection = 5 seconds

The HttpClient will be instanced once at starting the application.

```
private HttpClientHandler _httpClientHandler;
private static HttpClient _httpClient;

public MyTestClass()
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    _httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    _httpClientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
    _httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpClientHandler);
}
```

And the request method looks like this:

```
private HttpResponseMessage PerformRequest(string apiCommand, Entity.EntityTypes entityType, List<KeyValuePair<Entity.Attributes, string>> attributes)
{
    try
    {
        string relativeUri = string.Format("{0}/{1}?{2}&{3}",
              apiCommand,
              (apiCommand == Entity.API_SELECT) ? Entity.GetEntityCommand(entityType) : string.Empty,
              SYSTEM_AUTHENTICATION_PRODUCTION,
              PKI_USER_AUTHENTICATION);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Entity.Attributes, string> attribute in attributes)
           relativeUri += "&" + Entity.GetAttributeCommand(entityType, attribute.Key) + attribute.Value;

        return _httpClient.GetAsync(relativeUri).Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ClientException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
    }
    finally
    {
        LogReturn(CALL2);
    }
}
```

At the end of the day, the user is able to select a bunch of records from a grid and uses a method which is calling the PerformRequest method at the end. The PerformRequest will be called in a loop and the response will be analyzed every run.

The call looks like this:

```
public string GetInfos(string partNo)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    string result = null;
    try
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<Entity.Attributes, string>> attributes = new List<KeyValuePair<Entity.Attributes, string>>();
        attributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<Entity.Attributes, string>(Entity.Attributes.PartKey, PartNo));
        
        response = PerformRequest(Entity.API_SELECT, Entity.EntityTypes.Part, attributes);
        
        if (response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == MIME_TYPE_TEXT)
        {
            result = (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        response.Dispose();
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem occurs after > 200 runs of the PerformRequest method (some times 218, another time 220, ...). There will be thrown a WebException: "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel".

The surprise is, that no further call of the PerformRequest is working from now. All new calls ends in the same WebException. If I close the application und open it again, all is good and I can call the loop again.

The bigger surprise is, that if I copy the same REST-API-url which will be used by the application and paste it to a browser and excecute it, then it does take some time (I think the browser has to load the pki certificate from certificate store), then it loads the data correctly and afterwards my application also can do the loop one more again.

I did try everything I read from "using blocks" to non "using blocks" of the HttpClient/HttpClientHandler and ResponseMessages. I tried to pick the certificate manually by changing from HttpClientHandler to WebRequestHandler. Using the ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout property, also the HttpClientHandler.PreAuthenticate and HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose, ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue properties etc. I did this the last two days and I don't know what I can do further more.

Does anyone happen to have an idea what else it can be or why this does not work?
And why does it work again if the call took place in the browser?

Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: "The HttpClient will be instanced once at starting the application." <-- That's your problem: https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/ https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx

Comment: Thx for your comment. I already tested it with creating the HttpClient and HttpClientHandler every time the PerformRequest method is called. Sadly there is no difference in behaviour :-(